# Colors not the same when export After Effects

Tags: colors, export, adobe-after-effects

I'm trying to export my video from After Effects to `mov`. The problem is that the colors are different (washed out and flat) than shown in After Effects. In the Mac preview and on social media, the colors are washed out, while the colors are correct when opening in VLC player?

Can someone help? Left washed out colors, right the correct colors:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It would seem to me that you had `0-255`-level material that was converted to tv-safe levels (`16-240`). So basically, your original footage would be recorded in something like the `sRGB` color space (most DSLRs do so), while AE renders with e.g. [`Rec.709`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709#Digital_representation). Depending on the container (and the player in question), it could be that AE is not writing the color space into the file - or that the player doesn't read the color profile and simpy assumes the material is `sRGB`, thinking that `0-16` and `241-255` are allowed values. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) to help you, one would need to know a few more things: 1) Which version of AE are we talking about? 2) Where does the original footage come from (DSLR, already rendered on computer by program XYZ,...)? 3) Does VLC (or ffmpeg) reveal differences in the codec information (especially different `pix_fmt`s)? 4) What are your project settings in AE? 5) What are your footage interpretation settings in AE? 6) What are your exact export settings in AE? **All those things could cause this to happen, and it's very difficult to pinpoint your exact problem without this information.**

Comment: *the player doesn't read the color profile and simpy assumes the material is sRGB* --> that would be weird, considering that most video is limited range